# Looking for an "additive" binary graph operation that preserves subgraphs of high degree

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for a binary graph operation $\oplus$ that has the following properties for all undirected graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$.

1. If $d_1$ is the largest number for which $G_1$ has a subgraph of minimum degree $d_1$, and $d_2$ the largest such number for $G_2$, then the largest such number for $G_1 \oplus G_2$ should be $d_1 + d_2$. In other words, $$\max_{H \subseteq G_1} \delta(H) + \max_{H \subseteq G_2} \delta(H) = \max_{H \subseteq G_1 \oplus G_2} \delta(H),$$ where $\delta(H)$ denotes the minimum degree of the subgraph $H$.
2. $|G_1 \oplus G_2| \in O(|G_1| + |G_2|)$.
3. $G_1 \oplus G_2$ is computable in logarithmic space.

I believe the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product) for graphs satisfies the first and the third conditions, but the size of the product graph in this case is multiplicative (specifically $O(|G_1| \cdot |G_2|)$), not additive. I will be performing this operation a polynomial number of times, so a multiplicative increase in size is unacceptable.

*Edit: changed condition 3 to require a logarithmic space computation instead of a polynomial time computation.*

*Edit: changed condition 1 to require the maximum minimum degree over all subgraphs should be preserved.*

Comment: Do you need any structure of $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be preserved? Because the obvious answer is: let $a$ be the maximum value such that $G_1$ has a subgraph of minimum degree $a$ (essentially this is the degeneracy of $G_1$ and can be computed in linear time), let $b$ be defined in the same way from $G_2$, and define $G_1\oplus G_2$ to be a clique with $a+b+1$ vertices. Or if you want $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be subgraphs, define $G_1\oplus G_2$ to be the disjoint sum of this clique, $G_1$, and $G_2$.

Comment: @DavidEppstein You are of course correct. I made a mistake in describing the conditions necessary for the operation. It turns out that polynomial time is not allowed, only logarithmic space. This way the operation cannot determine whether a graph has a subgraph of minimum degree $a$ (because the High Degree Subgraph problem is $\mathsf{P}$-complete). I will edit the question to reflect this correction.

Comment: @argentpepper: Changing the complexity in this way does not avoid David's objection.

Comment: What if $G_1 \oplus G_2$ is simply a clique of size $|G_1| + |G_2|$ ?

Comment: I obviously did not describe the problem correctly, sorry about that. I have changed condition 1 to require that the maximum over all subgraphs of the minimum degree of the subgraph is preserved.

Comment: This still allows using a big clique as the sum, as David suggests.  What implicit condition do you have in mind that stops this?